# How do I concatenate a string onto an SQL query in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Basically I am attempted to auto populate a dropdown box with Team member names, this way in the future as team members get removed and added the dropdown will automatically adjusted.  This is the simple part, the hard part is that I also need “All” to show up in the dropdown box. Though I can’t seem to find any way to make this happen, so I am looking for either ideas, or for someone to tell me it is impossible.

At this point I just have the dropdown rowsource to ‘Table/Query’ and the query is:

```
 SELECT [Team Table].[Team_Member_ID], [Team Table].[USER_ID] 
    FROM [Team Table] 
    WHERE [Active] = True 
    ORDER BY [USER_ID] ;
```

I have made several attempts at added in a `UNION SELECT` or `UNION ALL SELECT` but I can't see to get that to run, SQL isn't my strongest suit so that could just be me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to create this function to do what I needed.

```vb
Sub ValueList(ByRef rs As Recordset, _
          strReturnColumn As String, _
          strCtrlToChange As String, _
          strDefaultValueIn As String, _
          frm As Form)


    Dim strRowSource    As String
    Dim strDefaultValue As String

    strDefaultValue = strDefaultValueIn
    strRowSource = ""
    rs.MoveFirst

    'If there is a Default Value add it to the RowSource
    If strDefaultValue <> "" Then
        strRowSource = strRowSource & strDefaultValue & ";"
    End If

    'Add all results onto the RowSource
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If CStr(rs.Fields(strReturnColumn) & "") <> "" Then
            strRowSource = strRowSource & CStr(rs.Fields(strReturnColumn) & "") & ";"
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    'Set Rowsource and default value
    frm.Controls(strCtrlToChange).RowSource = strRowSource
    frm.Controls(strCtrlToChange).DefaultValue = "'" & strDefaultValue & "'"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a union

```
SELECT 0     AS [Team_Member_ID], 'All' AS [USER_ID] 
UNION 
SELECT [team table].[team_member_id], [team table].[user_id] 
FROM   [team table] 
WHERE  [active] = true 
ORDER  BY [user_id];
```

Comment: Now this is is where I think Access is throwing a wrench in things due to this being the source of a combo box. When I attempt to click the dropdown I get an error from access saying "Query input must contain at least one table or query". I could technically 'Cheat' and simply create a fake user called 'All' though I really dislike muddying the database. I just feel like there is a way to do this properly.

Comment: What is the source (query) of the combobox?

Comment: After I ran through the wizard when making the combobox it generated the exact same query as the one I post above minus the "WHERE [Active] = True" hopefully that answers your question?

Comment: Tried changing that query also?

Comment: That is actually where I have been changing it, there is a number of places I want to do this so I am trying to avoid bloating the DB with queries and doing it directly in the source.

Comment: I suspect this answer didn't work at the time because Access can't handle a query without a table.  The trick is to create an use a `DUAL` table since access doesn't have it built in.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. This would show ALL at the top and sort the rest by USER_ID

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
     SELECT -1 as [Team_Member_ID], 'ALL' as [USER_ID]
     UNION   
     SELECT [Team Table].[Team_Member_ID], [Team Table].[USER_ID] FROM [Team Table] WHERE [Active] = True 
) as a
ORDER BY CASE WHEN  [USER_ID] = 'ALL' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, [USER_ID]
```

Comment: While attempting to run this Access returns the error "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CASE WHEN [USER_ID] = 'All' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END'."

Comment: My bad I wrote the query against SQL Server. try replacing CASE with  IIF([USER_ID] = 'ALL', 0, 1),

Comment: I suspect this answer didn't work at the time because Access can't handle a query without a table. The trick is to create an use a DUAL table since access doesn't have it built in.